# Oracle materialized view vs JPA query

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-batch

My case is that a third party prepares a table in our schema domain on which we run different spring batch jobs that look for mutations (diff between the given third party table and our own tables). This table will contain about 200k records on average.

My question is simply: does generating a material view up front provide any benefits vs running the query at runtime?
Since the third party table will be populated on our command (basically it's a db boolean field that is set to 1, after which a scheduler picks it up to populate the table. Don't ask me why it's done this way), the query needs to run anyway.

Obviously from an application point of view, it seems more performant to query a flat material view. However, I'm not sure if there is any real performance benefit, since the material view needs to be built on db level.

Thanks.

Comment: The benefit of `MV` could be that the difference is *uniquely* defined. If you let  *run your different spring batch jobs that look for mutations* there is some chance each of them will find something *bit* different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of a materialized view here is if you are running the multiple times (more so if the query is expensive and / or there is a big drop in cardinality).

If you are only hitting the query once then you there isn't going to be a huge amount in it.   You are running the same query either way and you have the overhead of inserting into the materialized view but you also have the benefit that you can tune this a lot easier than you could querying via JPA and could apply things like compression so less data is transferred back to the application but for 200k rows any difference is likely to be small.

All in all, unless you are running the same query multiple times then I wouldn't bother.

## Update

One other thing to consider is coupling.   Referencing a materialized view directly in JPA would allow you to update any logic without updating the application but the flip side of this is that logic is hidden outside the application which can make debugging a pain.

Also if you are just referencing a materialized view directly and not using any query rewrite or rollup features then am simple table created via `CTAS` would actually be better as you still have the precomputed data without the (small) overhead of maintaining the materialized view.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I thought so.

Comment: Added a quick update on perhaps one more thing to consider

Comment: The table being read doesn't get updated, it's a read-only operation. But thanks for the update.